# Set value of @Html.DropDownList based on Switch?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing an MVC 4 application. I have the below s on a view where I am using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) to alternate presenting either a Member Organizations drop down list or a Sponsors drop down list:

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="12345" name="Sponsor-Organization" checked class="userCreate-BSSwitch"/> 

    <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">   <div class="row switchOn">
        <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberOrgId, "Organization")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("OrganizationId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberOrgId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row switchOff">
            <dliv class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SponsorOrgId, "Sponsor")
            </dliv>
            <div class="editor-field" >
                @Html.DropDownList("SponsorId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SponsorOrgId)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I then have some jQuery being used to alternate which  is displayed based on the Switch value (On/Off) by adding/removing the Bootstrap `hide` class:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { $("#alert").alert('close'); }, 5000);
        $('.switchOff').addClass('hide');

    });  
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onText = 'Member';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offText = 'Sponsor';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offColor = 'info';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.animate = false;

    //$.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.size = 'large';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').bootstrapSwitch();
    });

    $('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
        var checked = state;
        if (checked) {
            $('.switchOn').removeClass('hide');
            $('.switchOff').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {
            $('.switchOff').removeClass('hide');
            $('.switchOn').addClass('hide');
        }
    });
```

What I can't seem to figure out though, is how to set the current drop down list value to blank (if a selection has been made) when the switch changes over to show the other drop down list. A user should only be able to make a selection for one of them, and I thought it would be easier to enforce  on this side instead of in the post back to my controller.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Added an `ID` to each dropdown and then reference it in my jQuery.

```
    <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">        
        <div class="row switchOn">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberOrgId, "Organization")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("OrganizationId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "OrgIdDropDown" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberOrgId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row switchOff">
            <dliv class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SponsorOrgId, "Sponsor")
            </dliv>
            <div class="editor-field" >
                @Html.DropDownList("SponsorId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SponsorIdDropDown" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SponsorOrgId)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    var checked = state;
    if (checked) {
        $('.switchOn').removeClass('hide');
        $('.switchOff').addClass('hide');
        $('#SponsorIdDropDown').val("");
    }
    else {
        $('.switchOff').removeClass('hide');
        $('.switchOn').addClass('hide');
        $('#OrgIdDropDown').val("");
    }
});
```